# How to change the size of android item icon menu in the toolbar?

Tags: android, xml

I want to change the width and height of the below image icon in tool bar:

[image: Icon Toolbar]

and this is the related `app\src\main\res\menu\main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        android:title="User"
        android:icon="@drawable/filterr"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [**`VectorDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable). Vector images do not lose quality when they are scaled. A vector image can be scaled indefinitely.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:width="24dp"
```

**`android:height`** - Used to define the intrinsic height the drawable.

**`android:width`** - Used to define the intrinsic width of the drawable.